# XSD schema - Either one or both

Tags: xsd, schema, element, xsd-validation

I it possible to make a choice scenario, like (A or B or Both). If yes, how can this be done with the following elements?

```
<xs:element name="a" type="typeA"  />
<xs:element name="b" type="typeB" />
```

Hope you can help.

Regards,
Nima

Answer (score 3):

You can see [XSD "one or both" choice construct leads to ambiguous content model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372395/xsd-one-or-both-choice-construct-leads-to-ambiguous-content-model)

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="...">
  <xs:element name="a" type="typeA"  />
  <xs:element name="b" type="typeB" />
  <xs:element name="...">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="a"/>
            <xs:element ref="b" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="b"/>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```